# Why the performance difference between `|` and `or` different for different values?

Tags: python, performance, logical-operators, boolean-logic

I was timing performance for operators, I found this:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("10000000<2 or 10000000>1000",number=10000000)
0.4213107880004827
>>> timeit.timeit("(10000000<2) | (10000000>1000)",number=10000000)
0.5472174039969104

>>> timeit.timeit("1000<200000 or 100>1000",number=10000000)
0.26014828799998213
>>> timeit.timeit("(1000<200000) | (100>1000)",number=10000000)
0.49938497000039206
```

Although the difference is sometimes miniscule, `or` consistently beats `|` for these large number comparisons (I am not really sure if this is because of the large numbers or not).

But then:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("0 or 1",number=10000000)
Out[134]: 0.17863203100023384
>>> timeit.timeit("0 | 1",number=10000000)
Out[135]: 0.06668136799999047

>>> timeit.timeit("00000 | 111111",number=10000000)
Out[136]: 0.06739834499967401
>>> timeit.timeit("00000 or 111111",number=10000000)
Out[137]: 0.1818816989998595

>>> timeit.timeit("True or False",number=10000000)
Out[138]: 0.12497510200046236
>>> timeit.timeit("True | False",number=10000000)
Out[139]: 0.06938139100020635

>>> timeit.timeit("False | True",number=10000000)
Out[140]: 0.0667262490005669
>>> timeit.timeit("False or True",number=10000000)
Out[141]: 0.1443343150003784
```

What's happening? Is this expected? I believed that `|` always checks both operands even if the first one evaluates to `True`. So at least for cases where 1st operand is `True`, shouldn't `or` be consistently faster?

Comment: `|` is bitwise or, `or` is logical or. They are two different operators.

Comment: Yes, I do get that. But why in some cases `bitwise` is faster, and in others `logical`? All it is comparing are `Truthy` and `Falsy`.

Comment: Because it doesn't compare Truthy and Falsy. It performs bitwise operations.

Comment: Okay, so `|` performs bitwise operation between `True` and `False` (effectively 1 and 0) and `or` performs logical operation between `True` and `False`. So shouldn't their performance be consistent for all cases? For example for integer containment checking `1 in range(1,5)` will always be slower than `0<1<5` because they work differently, then why not here?

Comment: `or` will stop on the first truthy part, and thus doesn't have to evaluate any next parts. `|` needs both part, and perform a computation on it, and *then* still evaluate what the result of that computation is.

Comment: I'm curious why you ask this question? Is it pure curiosity? Or are you (prematurely) optimizing for something? Or you intending to replace `or` with `|` (or vice versa)? Because obviously you can't do that.

Comment: You realize that `1000<200000 | 100>1000` evaluates probably differently than you intend (despite the suggestive spacing)? [`|` binds tighter than `<` or `>`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). Try `1000<100 | 1000>1001` for example, which has quite a different result than `1000<100 or 1000>1001`.

Comment: Agreed with @00 s comment. probably best to adapt your answer and put pranthesises around your comparisons. e.g. `(10000000<2) | (10000000>1000)`
and rerun the measurements.

Comment: gelonida I have updated the timings with parenthesis, and thanks for the answer. And @00 , pure curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

or and | are not at all the same operators.

`or` performs  logical shortcutting or whereas
`|` performs a bit wise or

```
result = expression1 or expression2
```

is identical to

```
if bool(expression1):
    result = expression1
else:
    result = expression2
```

so expression2 is not even evaluated if expression1 is true

whereas:

result = expression1 | expression2

performs a bit wise or of both values. so expression1 and expression2 must yield integers. (True is interpreted as integer 1)

look for example at followign output

```
In [8]: "{0:b}".format(0b100 | 0b001)                                           
Out[8]: '101'

In [9]: "{0:b}".format(0b100 or 0b001)                                          
Out[9]: '100'
```

**Clarification:**
If the operator on the right side of `|` / 'or' is fast to evaluate, then
it will probably '|' which is faster, as it will create branchless code.

On the other hand if the operator on the right side is CPU intensive and the left side is sometimes true and sometimes false, then `or` would be faster.

In your example the right hand side is a simple integer, so probably `|` might be a little bit faster. (Contrary to what I said in my initial answer)

Tiny operations with almost no exexution time difference have to be timed   over and over again. let's say time them a few hundred times during different times of the day. for both.

The problem with timeit is, that you execute python on an OS, that runs multiple processes and where you do not have a 100% predictible environment.

So I'd be really careful interpreting tiny differences in run time.

Comment: “So I agree with your assumption, that normally `or` should be faster than `|`” — that doesn’t logically follow. In fact, it’s not obvious which of these operations is faster on modern machines without knowing the specifics of how these operations are implemented internally. From *your* given description, `|` should trivially be faster than `or` since it’s branchless. Of course in actual implementations that’s different.

Comment: it depends on the expression on the right side of `or` / `|`  for a simple expression on the right side. '|' should be faster (being branchless).
For a CPU intensive right had operator `or` should be faster

Comment: “it depends on the expression on the right side” — yes, but that expression is a simple logical operation on a single integer.

Comment: Thanks Konrad. I adapted my answer